# Van der Waerden's theorem in $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

> Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of whole numbers and $l,m\in N$. Let's color all elements of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ in $k$ different colors. Prove that we can find two aritmetic progressions $A$ and $B$ of length $l$ and $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $A\times B$ contains only elements of the same color.

I know that this has something to do with Van der Waerden's theorem that has to be extended from $\mathbb{Z}^1$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and I have found some pretty neat theorems [here](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2007/01/26/the-multi-dimensional-polynomial-van-der-waerden-theorem/). But I could not make a direct connection.

Comment: So are you looking for a reference? This is a special case of the multidimensional Szemeredi's theorem. These "neat" theorems are related but not exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Or are you looking for a proof of a two dimensional Van der Waerden's theorem? (Previous title was better by the way.)

Comment: Yes, I want a proof. And I'll put the old title again. Thanks

Comment: Do you know that finitary version of Van der Waerden's theorem? That is the following: For any $l,k\in\mathbb N$, there exists some $N$ such that if the set $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ is colored by $k$ different colors, then there exists an arithmetic progression of length $l$ containing only elements of one color. It is not so hard to show that this is equivalent to Van der Waerden's theorem as you state it, but it's a lot easier to get from that to the result you want.

Comment: @Milo Brandt: yes, I know that version and I (think I) know how to prove it. However, I don't see how my problem statement is equivalent to the finitary version of VDW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than coloring $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, color $\mathbb Z \times [n]$ where $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is large enough that any $k$-coloring of $[n]$ contains an $m$-term arithmetic progression.

There are only finitely many possible monochromatic $m$-term arithmetic progressions to be found in $[n]$. One upper bound is $k \cdot \binom n2$, by choosing the color and the first two elements of the progression (which determine the other elements).

For every element $a \in \mathbb Z$, write down which monochromatic $m$-term arithmetic progression we find in $\{a\} \times [n]$. This is itself a $k\cdot\binom n2$-coloring of $\mathbb Z$, so it contains a monochromatic $l$-term arithmetic progression.

By staring at the thing we've found long enough, we realize that it is the thing we wanted to find.